Argo CD hooks not triggering Jobs upon code changes
I've followed the steps outlined in this blog to set up Argo CD resource hooks for triggering Jobs when there are changes in my codebase. However, I'm facing an issue where the hooks are not being triggered at all.
Here is the configuration of the Job I'm using:

I've attempted to trigger the synchronization process both by committing changes to the codebase and manually by clicking the "Sync" button in Argo CD. However, none of the hooks seem to be initiated.

Could someone please provide guidance on potential causes or troubleshooting steps to investigate this issue further? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations to help resolve this problem.

I figured it out. It turns out I have to put the Job in the same manifest file. It is also mentioned in the blog. For example:
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  generateName: presync-job
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PreSync
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: presync-job
          image: ubuntu     
          command: 
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - |
              echo "This is pre-sync"
      restartPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: main
          image: nginx:latest

